# advanced calculus by h loomis shlomo sternberg - question 5.30

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

**Notation:**
Let $V$ be a vector space. Given $T$ in $Hom(V)$ and a direct sum decomposition $V=\bigoplus_1^n V_i$, with corresponding projections $\{P_i\}_1^n$
we can consider the maps $T_{ij}=P_i\circ T\circ P_j$. Although $T_{ij}$ is from $V$ to $V$, we may also want to consider it as being from $V_j$ to $V_i$.
We picture the $T_{ij}$'s arranged schematically in a rectangular array similar to a matrix, as indicated below for $n=2$

\begin{array} {r|r} T_{11} & T_{12} \\ \hline T_{21} & T_{22} \\   \end{array}

Furthermore, since $T=\sum_{i,j}T_{ij}$, we call the doubly indexed family the block decomposition of $T$ associated with the given direct sum decomposition of $V$.

**Question:**

> Show that if $V=V_1\oplus V_2 \oplus V_3$ and $T\in Hom(V)$, then the subspaces $V_i$ are all invariant under $T$ if and only if the block diagram for $T$ is
> $$\begin{bmatrix} T_{11} & 0      & 0 \\
>                   0      & T_{22} & 0 \\
>                   0      & 0      & T_{33}
> \end{bmatrix}$$
> Show that $T$ is invertible if and only if $T_{ii}$ is invertible (as an element of $Hom (V_i)$) for each $i$.

I was able to solve the first part of the question but the second part doesn't seem right.
Here is a counter example for the second part:
Let $$V=\mathbb{R}^3$$
$$\begin{align}
V_1=\{\langle x,0,0 \rangle \space | \space x\in\mathbb{R}\} \\
V_2=\{\langle 0,y,0 \rangle \space | \space y\in\mathbb{R}\} \\
V_3=\{\langle 0,0,z \rangle \space | \space z\in\mathbb{R}\}
\end{align}$$
notice that $$V=V_1\oplus V_2 \oplus V_3$$
Let $T\in Hom(V)$, such that $$T(\langle x,y,z \rangle) = \langle y,x,z \rangle$$
$T$ is invertible ($T^{-1}=T$).

Let $P_i$ be the projection of $V$ onto $V_i$, $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.
For example $P_1(\langle x,y,z \rangle)=\langle x,0,0 \rangle$
We have defined $T_{11}\in Hom(V_1)$ as $T_{11}=P_1\circ T\circ P_1$.
Let $\langle x,0,0 \rangle \in V_1$.
We have, $$T_{11}(\langle x,0,0 \rangle) = P_1\circ T \circ P_1(\langle x,0,0 \rangle)= P_1 \circ T(\langle x,0,0 \rangle) = P_1(\langle 0,x,0 \rangle)=\langle 0,0,0 \rangle$$
Hence $T_{11}=0$ and not invertible. but $T$ is invertible therefore the claim doesn't hold.

Is there something wrong with my counter example or the question is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the second part assumes the result of the first part: the $V_i$ must be $T$-invariant so that the decomposition takes that diagonalized form. Your counterexample $T$ does not preserve the $V_i$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The second part does hold if we assume that the $V_i$ are invariant under $T$. The question is written very poorly if that is the case.

Comment: The wording is unfortunately ambiguous, but I think you're right to assume the first part.